# On click scroll inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a wrapping block (like sidebar) with smaller block inside. I want to make the smaller block scroll to the top of the wrapping block (and it would look like a title) when clicked.

I have tried a lot of stuff but nothing works, I just can't understand the logic how it must work.

```
$(".second").click(function() {
  $('.wrap').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Update: I think I explained my problem wrong. Maybe this way: Imagine long list of contacts and when you click on certain contact, all content scrolls until this contact will be at the top of visible area.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimavaluh/ryXFt/3815/)

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your logic is making the `.wrap` element scroll to the top. You need to focus on making the `.second` element scroll to the top within the `.wrap`.

Comment: Let me know you want like this:- http://jsfiddle.net/6k6av5s2/  (check css 
 of all classes after animation happen). If yes then i will post it as an answer

Comment: @AlivetoDie, thats not exactly what i want to do

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/q1qxuekm/

Comment: @ManuelOtto, YEEEESSSSS!!!)) Thanks so much!! Post it as answer, please

Comment: I'll post it as answer for ppl who might have the same prob, kk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to determine the elements position inside the scrollable div and add that to the current scrollTop value:

```
scrollTop: $(e.currentTarget).position().top + $('.wrap').scrollTop()
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1qxuekm)